# Конфликт одинаковых css классов

Tags: css

такой вопрос, есть bootstrap и bootstrap mdb, в том и том модуле есть класс X, который меня больше устраивает на bootstrap (не mdb), но класс с таким же названием есть в mdb, и когда я указываю класс  X на нужном компоненте, как вы уже поняли грузится с mdb, а не bootstrap,  скажите пожалуйста как мне указывать с какого файла брать css класс?

Comment: Никак, классы для всех общие и нужно изначально делать имена классов несовпадающими

Comment: @andreymal хорошо, спасибо :)

Comment: Попробуйте в css в конце значения класса поставить !important